# PHP code for searching a word into text file and displaying the contents

Tags: php, design-patterns, matching

sam.php

```
<?php

$file = "tp2.txt";
$fh1 = fopen($file, "r") or die("File ($file) does not exist!");
$fh2 = fopen("tp.txt", "r") or die("File ($file) does not exist!");
$fh3 = fopen("tp3.txt", "w") or die("File ($file) does not exist!");
$members=array();
$tags=array();
$i = 0;
while (!feof($fh1))
{
$members[] = fgets($fh1);
}
while (!feof($fh2))
{
$tags[] = fgets($fh2);
}
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($members);$i++)
    {
        $chk=$members[$i];
        //echo $chk;

        //fwrite($fh3,$members[$i]);
        for($j=0;$j<sizeof($tags);$j++)
        {
            $n = preg_quote($chk);

            if (preg_match_all("/\b$n\b/", $tags[$j]))
            //if (preg_match('/'."\b$chk\b".'/', $tags[$j]))
            {

                fwrite($fh3,$tags[$j]);
            }
        }
        //if(in_array($chk,$tags))echo "success";


    }


fclose($fh1);
fclose($fh2);
fclose($fh3);
?>
```

tp.txt:

> And Battlefield 3 was damn good, so that’s saying a lot.
>   This series of games is the best one seen yet.
>   Battlefield 4 is the  best Battlefield yet. 
>   Best way to handle it is solving it.
>   It is good that you noticed it at an early stage.
>   He was just great.

tp2.txt:

> good
>   best

Question:
I want to search all the occurrences of the word "good" and "best" to be found from file tp.txt and display the respected lines that contains those words. In output it gives all the lines from tp.txt irrespective of whether match is found or not.
Please anyone help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$text = file('tp.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$words = file('tp2.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$pattern = implode('|', $words);

foreach ($text as $string) {
    if (1 === preg_match("/(?:$pattern)/", $string))
        file_put_contents('tp3.txt', $string, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: But I want that each line to be written on a new line in the text file(tp3.txt)....so how would I do that in file_put_contents????

Comment: `file_put_contents('tp3.txt', $string . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);` or remove `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag from `$text` initialization code.